# In-App Purchase Issue,

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am working on an in-app purchase. I am getting following error:

```
CheckoutPurchase.setError: type=PURCHASE_FAILED, code=3, permissionCode=-1, 
message=Your payment could not be processed at this time. 
You may receive an email asking you to verify your account.
```

Can anyone know how to solve this issue ?

Comment: _You may receive an email asking you to verify your account._  Did you receive any email ?

Comment: did not receive any email